# Polylang Switcher

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, polylang

I am a beginner at word press and I've stumbled upon this problem.

I have 3 languages that are displayed, which are English, Chinese & Indonesian. I want to display them in a way that if you are on English, the title of the language switcher should be Other Languages.

The 2 other languages should be titled according to own languages, and if I am on Chinese, the title should be displayed as Other Languages in Chinese, and the 2 other languages titles should be displayed as their own. Are there any ways to do it?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Go to appearance->menus->select menu you want to edit, in language switcher you have options to set, what you need is don't show current language checked